# Saving and Restoring Lights (HMCharacteristics)

Tags: ios, swift, homekit

I'm using lights connected with HomeKit for notifications. I'd like to take the current state (color, brightness, on/off) of each light being used, and restore the lights to that state after the notification is finished. However it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's how I'm trying to accomplish this:

I have a dictionary that maps a dictionary of characteristics and their values to each light (HMService).

I run the following code to process and save the current state of the lights:

```
for service in services {
    for characteristic in service.characteristics {
        if characteristic.characteristicType == HMCharacteristicTypeHue ||
            characteristic.characteristicType == HMCharacteristicTypeSaturation ||
            characteristic.characteristicType == HMCharacteristicTypeBrightness {
            characteristic.readValue(completionHandler: { (error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    var characteristicsStore: [String : Any?] = [:]
                    if let existingCharacteristics = self.services[service] {
                        characteristicsStore = existingCharacteristics
                    }
                    characteristicsStore.updateValue(characteristic.value, forKey: characteristic.characteristicType)
                    self.services.updateValue(characteristicsStore, forKey: service)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Then, after the notification is complete, I run this code which is supposed to set the characteristics of the lights back to the values I've stored, but isn't working:

```
for (service, characteristics) in services {
    for (characteristicType, characteristicValue) in characteristics {
        if let characteristic = service.characteristics.first(where: { (aCharacteristic) -> Bool in
            aCharacteristic.characteristicType == characteristicType
        }) {
            characteristic.writeValue(characteristicValue, completionHandler: { (error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    didSucceed = false
                    numberOfErrors += 1
                } else {
                    print("Updated \(characteristic.characteristicTypeToString()) to \(characteristicValue as! Float)")
                }
            })
        } else {
            print("Did not find the characteristic")
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error: Unconfigured Parameter, when I attempt to read or write the values.

UPDATE:

I was actually making progress, and then performed an update on my Hue lights. Now I'm worse off than I was before. I can't access any of the HMService objects 'accessory' properties, making it impossible to check to see if the accessory is reachable without a ton of rewriting.

If anyone could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong or if there's something I'm completely missing, it would be greatly appreciated.